# Store or get User ID as PHP session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

In a login system, we are using a table to store login details of students. Columns are : StudentID (int, Auto Increment, Primary Key) StudentName (Varchar, 50) and StudentPassword (Varchar, 16). When the Student logins, we are getting session variable : $_SESSION['Username']. Now, since we are using the StudentID as primary key, it is used to link other tables in the database, we need to store / Get the StudentID as session variable. How to get this extra column as server variable?

Comment: Store it the same way that you store the username in a session variable

Comment: that password length looks suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do this at the point of login. Say we got a database row $row

```
     $_SESSION['user-id'] = $row['user_id'];
```